Would a middle ground between unit and integration tests be optimal
I've read many posts about unit tests only testing one object/class and mocking of objects should only be for direct dependencies of the object under tests.  The only other option discussed for testing are full integration tests.
Why isn't there encouragement for higher level "unit" testing that tests multiple objects at a time?  If an application that has components A, B, and C and the application is supposed to do X, Y, and Z, then create tests for X, Y, and Z. This would exercise the code for A, B, and C components.
If there is code in A, B, or C that is not covered by the X, Y, and Z tests, then either that code is not needed or additional high level tests should be added. If needed, low level unit tests for A, B, or C could be added to augment the X, Y, and Z tests.
Unit tests for A, B, and C individually creates a lot of duplicate work and makes it difficult to refactor code.  There may be some loss of precision of pinpointing where errors are, but with a debuggers, it is generally fairly quick to diagnose a problem.  Additionally, lower level tests can be implemented if needed.  Why does testing have to only be single object unit test and full application integration tests?

Why would unit tests for A, B and C create duplicate work, unless there is duplicate code in A, B, and C that shouldn't be there?

"Why does testing have to only be single object unit test and full application integration tests?" - who says it does?

@DocBrown Established practices, predominant in the industry, say that's what it is.  (This is not a statement endorsing it.)

The problem with "established practices" is that there is no central authority on what those practices are, nor is there agreement on what they are to begin with (much less on the definition of "unit test").

@GregBurghardt "established practices" are what you see if you observe what people do out there.  If nine out of ten shops do it, it is established practice. Unit testing has a pretty clear definition, see Wikipedia. There are some, like Ian Cooper, who try to redefine it with mental acrobatics, but they are not particularly convincing.

@MikeNakis: to be fair, that's a blurry definition, and when eleven out of ten shops interpret it differently, I would say there is no strong agreement about it.

Part of this is test maintainability.  Unit tests that are small in scope are easy to maintain.  Once we start adding more and more objects and their corresponding dependencies, the more complex and time consuming they become write and maintain.  Ask yourself if you want to maintain a suite of unit tests where each one has 10-20 services that need to be mocked, and I would say let's not do that and maybe some refactoring is needed.  But certainly, if a set of objects only has a few dependencies I see no reason why unit tests couldn't be written for those objects as a whole.


I've read many posts about unit tests only testing one object/class and mocking of objects should only be for direct dependencies of the object under tests. The only other option discussed for testing are full integration tests.

This style is wrong. I'm sorry but it is. Oh sure I could say, well that's one way to do it. No it's not. It's terrible. I know because I've worked in shops that insisted on this style exclusively and it's the death of object oriented programming. Do this while taking test coverage seriously and you will write procedural code just to avoid making another object that you'd have to test.
Fowler wrote about this style. He called the tests solitary tests and the style that insists on them mockist. He was very clear that this is not his style.
Now I'm not opposed to writing the occasional solitary test. That has all its dependencies mocked so nothing happens that isn't the fault of the object under test. But insisting that every object get tested up this way is an abomination of structural thinking over behavioral thinking. Test every object this way and you’re pouring glue all over the Legos.
Just as you should not hack your way past access modifiers to test a private method you should not hack your way past an API to test a private object.
Why? Because abstraction is a good thing. Let me hide stuff where it doesn't matter if I change how it works so long as you get the behavior you need. This gives us the freedom to change things, not just inside objects, but between objects. So long as it does the same thing, who cares?
The very existence of the Facade Pattern proves that an object can abstract many other objects. Those other objects deserve their privacy as much as any private method.

Why isn't there encouragement for higher level "unit" testing that tests multiple objects at a time?

Because you haven't looked hard enough. Fowler encouraged it. Kent Beck encouraged it. Uncle Bob encouraged it. I'm encouraging it. The ones who don't, often turn out to be selling mocking tools.
The other side may argue: if you are testing multiple objects at a time then you are doing some form of integration testing.
To which I ask, what makes objects so special that it's only when we integrate them that we care? Some testable languages get by just fine with no objects at all. Or do we just have to call any test of anything that integrates with anything an integration test? If that's the case your methods had better only have one line of code. Or you'll need to mock those other lines of code.
Sorry but this way of thinking became popular simply because it makes it easy to brainlessly ding someone in a code review. "Hey, you added a Foo class; where's your FooTest class?". Uggg.
What then, is an integration test? It's a test that doesn't have a carefully carved out testable unit under it. The unit should be deterministic code (so no IO). The unit should be fast (so no IO). The unit should be easy to run (so no making me edit config files). The unit should be something you can run multiple tests on at the same time (no weird side effects). In short, the unit is your functional code. Carved up as thickly or finely as you like. Objects really have nothing to do with it.
Writing code you can test this way doesn't come for free. It's work. The pattern you end up following has a name: Functional Core, Imperative Shell.
That pattern right there admits that some things don't fit in the functional core. Some things are outside it. Some times those things need testing. That's what you throw an integration test at.

Some think I'm being too restrictive with IO here. Well it's not just me. The first three things Michael Feathers forbids in a unit test (DB, network, filesystem) are all IO.
It's not just him, functional programming insists you be formal with IO because it insists code be deterministic which is a very good thing for a test to be. Haskell lets you do IO but makes you use a monad so that IO actions are "cleanly separated from the purely functional core of the language."=. Not programming in Haskell isn't a good excuse to not maintain this separation.
It's not just fans of functional programming. Google has rules about "small tests".Thank you Magnie Mozios

The other important constraints on small tests are that they aren’t allowed to sleep, perform I/O operations, or make any other blocking calls.

The I/O bit has a foot note:

There is a little wiggle room in this policy. Tests are allowed to access a filesystem if they use a hermetic, in-memory implementation."
Testing Overview - Adam Bender

It's really hard to just look at a test and it's unit and tell if it's following these rules. So please, find some way to clearly signal which kind of test you've written. Don't follow these rules and then don't tell anyone. Don't disregard these rules and then don't tell anyone. Please tell us which kind of test you've written. I'd like to know if I might need to rerun the test. Please, I'm begging you here.

The accent on no IO is a bit too hard. If IO is managed by a framework, the only way to remove IO is to mock framework, which is often impractical. I write integration tests with IO then and often get useful failures from them. Yes, an architecture, that is defined by framework is horrible, but mocked framework is useless - it is never detailed enough to detect complex interaction bugs.

@Basilevs you want IO in your test? Fine. Just call it an integration test. Have the courage to clearly label things.

@Basilevs I/O doesn't necessarily mean slow like an end-to-end test. I've written plenty of tests that utilize I/O in temp folders that perform blazing fast, and are also independent. But I didn't call them unit tests. They were still testing the infrastructure. I called them integration tests even though they executed nearly as fast as my unit tests. I/O is absolutely the line between "unit test" and "integration test" because it is non-deterministic.

@GregBurghardt threading is also non-determenistic. Surely we don't need to call a test  an integration test, if it uses or tests multiple execution threads? Can we consider a temporary directory to be a part of Unit's configuration?

@Basilevs, and what's the harm if you do? I think people get too hung up on everything needing to be a unit test. Call it what it is, and test it. Testing it is the important part.

@GregBurghardt agreed. The point of calling them what they are is that you can separate them and treat them differently.  It only takes one slow test to ruin a fast test suite.

Thanks for the explanation and all references.  I'll use them to, hopefully, steer things in a better direction.

@GregBurghardt I disagree about I/O being non-deterministic. In context of dedicated temp folders an I/O error is about as likely as OOM during test execution. You don't call unit tests non-deterministic just because testing machine can run out of memory. Separating fast and slow tests is another thing - if you do heavy I/O, it can be slow, but so can be a CPU-based test. That's a different distinction.

@Frax true, but equally the reason we don’t allow IO in the unit isn’t because the HD might be full. And it isn’t just because a write over IO can run 1000 times slower. The big reason is because it represents shared mutable state. That can easily make it non-deterministic. If your testing plan says “if it fails try running it again” you’ve created an unreliable test. Sometimes that’s unavoidable. But it’s also something you should communicate. I’m willing to rerun an integration test. But not a unit test. That I’m willing to rewrite or relabel.

@candied_orange the test temporary directory is usually not shared. Imagine a disk cache with an exclusive access to underlying directory. Is it not a unit?

@Basilevs Allowing IO into the unit will not reliably cause trouble. Just potentially cause trouble. Which makes it hard to test for. Which means we have to know what we're doing. I become confident when we remove or mock IO out of the unit. If you run each test with it pointing at it's own temp dir to achieve isolation, and in a cache so it's fast then it sounds like you know what you're doing. It also sounds like you mocked out your IO. I never said you had to use some mocking tool to do it. But maybe that's not a mock. Maybe that's how your operational code works. If so, great.

@Basilevs just understand, if you don't make that scheme understandable to people it will all fall apart the moment some newbie makes changes. Now you have to explain why some IO is ok in the unit and some is not.

I think it's clear that IO is not the dividing line between unit test and integration test, I'm quite confused why there's such the dogmatic insistence that it is. And that's despite this post spending time criticizing Mockist dogmatism or referencing articles that do.  Is this just a lack of imagination here?  You can't test a file reader at all with out file IO, yet testing the functions for one would clearly be a unit in some of the same eyes here with out IO. IO does not have to be "slow", it does not have to be "non-deterministic" any more than allocating any memory at all would be.

Additionally there seems to be more loss of imagination, there are tests that obstensibly test a unit which take forever to run and are non deterministic.    I guess people in the TDD book world don't really encounter actual scientific code, where you don't even know the metric for what makes your code work?   And then a step down from that, is code that has to maintain certain statistical properties, and sometimes verifying this is very computationally expensive, and needs loots of randomly generated values.

The real lesson is that there virtually zero absolutes in software engineering, even in the saying "there are virtually zero absolutes"  You're classifying hot dogs and sandwiches with these unnecessary hard lines, unit test and integration test blur into one another at some point with your current definitions, even if the "ends" of the spectrum appear distinct.

@Krupip I think it's clear that IO is a very useful dividing line. Michael Feathers used it. Functional programming used it. Can you happen to write IO using code that meets the deterministic needs of unit testing? Yes. It is easy to spot that in a code review? No. So if you want to violate this rule you'd better be willing to make it easy to see how safe your code is. Because I'm sick of tests that I have to rerun when they fail. Call them whatever you like but such tests need to be in a different bucket with a clear label.

@Krupip "You can't test a file reader at all with out file IO" that is true, because a file reader is code that 'integrates' the application with the filesystem. I've never written a file reader though, I let the standard library of the programming language I'm using do the actual reading and give me the bytes (and that is easy to mock, usually).

For anyone interested in reading additional information about how others do testing..  The "Testing Overview" chapter in Software Engineering at Google is pretty good. The "Test Size" and "Test Scope" sections are quite relevant to this question and answer.

@MagnieMozios thank you for that. You inspired an edit.

What you describe is actually classic unit test. In classic unit tests, you only mock dependencies when necessary, e.g. if the dependency is non-deterministic or impractically slow.
In contrast there is the "mockist"-style, also called the London school, which insist that all dependencies to the class under tests should be mocked.
Martin Fowler describes the two scools of thought like this.

the big issue here is when to use a mock (or other double).
The classical TDD style is to use real objects if possible and a
double if it's awkward to use the real thing. So a classical TDDer
would use a real warehouse and a double for the mail service. The kind
of double doesn't really matter that much.
A mockist TDD practitioner, however, will always use a mock for any
object with interesting behavior. In this case for both the warehouse
and the mail service.

https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html
The mockist approach have a number of downsides, as you have observed. Fundamentally it is more work but result in more brittle and less through testing. The one advantage of the mockist approach is it is very easy to pinpoint the error when a test fails, since the test only touch a single class.

Thanks.  "classic" is a reasonable name, but doesn't seem descriptive enough.  It assumes a knowledge about the history or testing.

@Thor: One way to think of it is not "Classic" as in "Classic vs Modern", but as in "Classical Guitar versus Electrical Guitar."; one lets the artifacts (The results of the test, or the sound of the guitar strings) come from the interactions with the guitar's shape, and the other routes the interaction through another means, that can be more easily amplify the artifacts. Both can be "Modern", and they both do the thing, but they do it in subtle but significantly different ways.

@Thor Fowler also uses the terms "sociable" vs "solitary" unit tests, where sociable tests include dependencies while solitary tests mocks all dependencies. See https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html

As an aside, the main advantage of mockist testing suggests that its ideal use case is if a classic test fails, as a means to isolate the failure point.

"The one advantage of the mockist approach is it is very easy to pinpoint the error when a test fails" -- In theory.  But SOLID principles can drive a lot of complexity out of the objects proper and into the interactions between them, and mockist testing won't catch bugs in those interactions.

@WayneConrad Absolutely agree. The mockist approach makes it easier to pinpoint the errors it finds - at the cost of finding fewer errors overall.

@AlexanderThe1st I see your point.  I still think a more descriptive name would be better.  Maybe something like holistic (I'm sure there other better ones).  Classic could mean many things.  But, I do see what you are saying.

@JacquesB "The mockist approach makes it easier to pinpoint the errors it finds - at the cost of finding fewer errors overall." -- Well said

This is a huge topic, so I will only write a moderate amount of text here, and refer you to external sources for further reading.
Disclosure: I am the author of the external sources.
The way Automated Software Testing is practiced in the industry today involves Unit Testing with Mock Objects. By established practice, these three concepts are regarded as inextricably tied together:

If you want to be doing Testing, you have to be doing Unit Testing.
If you want to be doing Unit Testing, you have to be using Mock Objects.

That is what the vast majority of programmers all over the world do.
And it is all deeply misguided.
The sole reason of existence of Unit Testing is to achieve Defect Localization: when the system malfunctions, we want to know exactly which component causes the malfunction.
Defect localization is in fact a huge issue in Hardware Testing, where the concept of Unit Testing originates from. It is also of some importance in Software Testing, it but is not nearly as important. Nonetheless, Unit Testing is the only tool that people know, so that is what people do.
In order to achieve Defect Localization, Unit Testing demands that each component must be tested in strict isolation from the rest of the system. To achieve this, people use Mock Objects. The use of Mock Objects is misguided because they are laborious, and they constitute testing against the implementation instead of testing against the interface, so they are over-specified, presumptuous, and lead to tests that are fragile and non-reusable. For more information, see michael.gr - If you are using mock objects you are doing it wrong.
Here is the abstract of that paper:

The practice of using Mock Objects in automated software testing is examined from a critical point of view and found to be highly problematic. Opinions of some well known industry speakers are cited. The supposed benefits of Mock Objects are shown to be either no real benefits, or achievable via alternative means.

(Note: the well known industry speakers that are cited include Martin Fowler and Kent Beck.)
So, the "higher level unit testing that tests multiple objects at a time" that you are speaking of in your question does not exist, because it would not be Unit Testing. If you are testing multiple objects at a time then you are doing some form of integration testing, and if you are testing all objects at the same time then you are doing end-to-end testing.
I have come up with an alternative technique, which goes quite a long way towards achieving Defect Localization; it just does not achieve it perfectly, in exchange for other benefits. I call this technique Incremental Integration Testing.  Perhaps it is close to your notion of testing multiple objects at a time. You can read about it here: michael.gr - Incremental Integration Testing
Here is the abstract of that paper:

A new method for Automated Software Testing is presented as an alternative to Unit Testing. The new method retains the benefit of Unit Testing, which is Defect Localization, but eliminates the need for mocking, thus greatly lessening the effort of writing and maintaining tests.

It is hard to tell why people are stuck with Unit testing. Maybe it is adherence to tradition, maybe it is cargo cult engineering, maybe it is reluctance to admit the magnitude of their prior fallacy and reluctance to write off the monumental effort that they have already put into it.

"Defect localization" is a buzzword I'll need to remember. I've always felt the greatest benefit of a unit test is realized when it fails, not when it passes.

I know I've run into this before on this site, but your answer reminds me of social vs isolated unit tests (though a specific reference eludes me at the moment).

Very helpful.  Thanks.  I also enjoyed reading your blog.

@GregBurghardt Well, of course. Passing tests are pretty much useless - in the same fashion an insurance is useless while everything is going well. It is indeed the failing that is their purpose. Unfortunate fact is that because we don't know beforehand which are going to fail, so we have to write and run them all.

There are multiple schools of thought when it comes to unit testing.
In his writing about unit testing, Martin Fowler writes about the classic style and the mockist style. The classic style prefers sociable unit tests, which rely on other units - other methods, or even other classes - when testing. The mockist style, on the other hand, isolates the unit - the method or the class unit test - using stubs, mocks, fakes, and other types of test doubles.
A lot of this is probably at a lower level than what you are thinking. If an application is supposed to do X, Y, and Z, those likely wouldn't be tested by unit tests. The application would be tested by something that I would call something like "acceptance tests" or "scenarios". I tend to think about unit tests as more developer- and technology-facing rather than user-facing, and this is more in line with how the Agile Testing Quadrants are described.

The better term is functional test. Acceptance tests can't be automated by definition, scenario is a vague term.

@Basilevs The application-level tests don't have to be limited to functionality. Tests could assert performance such as timing or memory consumption, for example. I don't see why acceptance tests can't be automated - there may be specific classes, such as usability or accessibility tests that can only be automated to a limited extent (such as checking against well-defined rules). Tools such as Gherkin use the term "scenario" to refer to an illustration of a business rule that contains the steps to be tested, so I've seen it leak into other testing terminology.

Thanks.  I am looking for a good term for this testing.  I'm not sure acceptance is quite right.  To me, that implies that if the tests pass then the product is accepted or acceptable.  I think the tests I'm describing are more functional that complete acceptance tests.  Performance and load testing would be part of acceptance in my mind.
I like the term behavior testing, but that is already taken.


Why isn't there encouragement for higher level "unit" testing that tests multiple objects at a time?

That's still unit testing. You seem to be operating under the belief that a "unit" in "unit test" refers to a class (or instance of that class). This is not the case. A "unit" is not one class/instance, it is one component.
"Component" is a vague term, and that is by design. You need to draw the boundary of what constitutes a component based on context, which is why there's no universal definition of it available.
If your argument is that there is a group of objects that work together to achieve a common goal, then it's possible that these are really just a unit, for the purpose of unit testing.

Why isn't there encouragement for higher level "unit" testing that tests multiple components at a time?

Because once you use more than one component, it's no longer a unit test, it's an integration test. You seem to be operating under the belief that integration tests refer to the widest possible "end to end" that they can. This is not the case.
"Integration" effectively means "more than one unit" (I'm using this phrasing to contrast it to unit tests). The amount of units is undetermined, other than it being two or more. You could have a massive end-to-end test, or one with a limited scope. Both are integration tests, for the purpose of distinguishing them from unit tests.
Generally speaking, I see people refer to the widest possible integration tests as "end to end tests", i.e. when maximizing the amount of real components that they can in order to get the realest test execution that is reasonably possible.
Based on your question, it seem to me that X/Y/Z are test scenarios that represent application use cases, and therefore seem to be end to end tests. That's perfectly fine, nothing wrong with that, but they operate on a very different level than your components (units). For one, the use cases often don't include technical considerations that are not visible by the user (when dealing with requirements in the form of user stories). Examples of this can include under the hood optimizations (e.g. internal caching) or long term maintenance tasks (e.g. scheduled archiving).

Unit tests for A, B, and C individually creates a lot of duplicate work and makes it difficult to refactor code.

This is likely born from your incorrect interpretation that a "unit" must constitute an individual class/instance. As mentioned before, this is not the case.
However, I also want to address the general point you're trying to get at. Unit tests do not inhibit refactoring of an implementation of the unit. The only thing that a unit test depends on is the public behavior (i.e. contract) of the unit. That's inevitable, as unit tests are specifically constructed as being interactions and observations with the unit, which you inherently achieve by interacting with its interface and/or its dependencies (which together form the contract I referred to earlier)
But even if you need to refactor the technical nuts and bolts of the contract, e.g. add a parameter here or remove a method there, as long as you're not rewriting the high level responsibility of the unit, then these changes might affect the implementation of the unit test (as the code itself changes), but not necessarily the choice of which tests should be run on this unit.
We strike on a similar point from the previous paragraph. There is a difference in needing to update the implementation of a test (due to a change in the unit's contract), and needing to re-evaluate the overall goal of the test suite (which only happens when the unit starts adding/removing responsibilities). The latter is a significant redesign of your unit, which means that the impact this has on your tests is inevitable, and not indicative of a problem. It's a natural consequence.
All too often, I see developers point this out as a problematic situation, and the conclusion they draw from it is "I shouldn't have written these unit tests so I didn't need to refactor them now". I strongly disagree with that conclusion. A much more pertinent observation here is that you shouldn't be making major alterations to component contracts on a regular basis.
Needing to do so on a regular basis suggests that (a) you did not sufficiently analyze your technical design before you started building and (b) you did not build your codebase to be sufficiently change-friendly in order to accommodate future changes to the codebase (as evidenced by making frequent contract changes).
In other words, either you're doing an unreasonable amount of significant redesigns, and/or the codebase you've built is unreasonably change-unfriendly. Both of these possibilities are way more important to identify and rectify, instead of trying to justify why you should've written less tests in the first place.

A significant factor in the approach taken to testing depends on what order you go about writing the code in the first place.
In TDD, you're supposed to start with the test that describes the functionality you want, then you implement the code that actually does it.  During the course of implementing it, you might decide to break up the functionality between multiple classes that need not be individually tested because they're already being tested as a composite.  This is a top-down approach.
In some other methodologies, you might start bottom-up by implementing a single class first and then writing the tests for it.  This gives you a well-tested foundation on which to build the next class that consumes it.
Either way, it's fairly common to have multiple classes involved in a single test (though more common in the former than the latter); that can still be a unit test if it's all related functionality and not testing the entire system.  And either kind might need to mock out external dependencies not relevant for the test (or relevant but difficult to use the real thing).
Neither approach is inherently better than the other (zealots notwithstanding) and you'll often find yourself reaching for both in different contexts.

Are you familiar with the test pyramid?
When building production software, it's important to consider the pro's and con's of each potential design. There will only be one implementation of the software, so it's important to select a single design that both fits the current needs and accommodates future changes.
However, this isn't the case with automated tests. Mixing together different styles is not only possible, but widely considered best practice. Focused low level tests can identifying issues with isolated sections of code while broad high level tests exercise all of the software to identify issues with how the components interact with each other. Using multiple styles of automated tests leverages the strengths of each and provides more robust testing than is possible with any single approach. This is also efficient as you don't have to write or execute complex tests for every possible edge case; those can be covered at the lower levels.
I'll use my current job to provide a concrete example of the test pyramid in action. Our software consists of dozens of microservices mostly running Java and Spring Boot.

At the lowest level are unit tests focus on individual methods of any class with any logic. These help us quickly identify bugs and provide confidence as we develop features.
At the next level up, we use the Spring Boot testing framework to stand up an entire service while mocking outside services. These tests run through common use cases to validate that the components are configured correctly and working together as intended.
In addition, there are contract tests (via PACT) that verify that the provider of an API continues to respond in the manner expected by clients. This reinforces assumptions made in other tests and alerts teams to when changes may cause other services to fail.
At the highest level, our SDETs maintain a suite of end-to-end tests that simulate end users and third party systems to exercise key features of the platform. These are crucial for identifying where changes in one service have unintended consequences on other services.

Each of these automated tests are run at different stages of our development process, allowing us to identify defects early while also not missing problems that are only visible at the larger scale. This wouldn't be possible if we relied only on automated tests in the "middle ground."

I've read many posts about unit tests only testing one object/class
I'm not sure I agree with this statement to be honest. Unit tests test the very lowest level things - usually functions and methods etc. Although these unit tests are usually grouped together by class. I tend to mirror the structure of the Code Under Test (CUT) in my test projects (including folders), but this is purely a personal preference.
There are lots of other types of testing, integration tests are but one. There are also:
Component Testing
Test logical groups of units together
Behavioural Testing
Tests certain behaviours and corner cases
System Testing
The most comprehensive type of testing. And of course...
Integration Testing
Tests a number of units (or components) together.

Mocks v Objects
As others have outlined, unit tests that use mocks don't test using "proper objects" (whatever they are) so some people view this in a pejorative way. But the whole point is to narrow down the blast radius when things go wrong so you want as few moving parts as possible.
You can use other sorts of test doubles depending on your purpose. Martin Fowler does a reasonable job of covering them here but I see new ones appearing in the literature all the time.

I've seen something of a disturbing pattern where developers represent higher types of testing e.g. component/behavioural as unit tests. Probably because they don't want to create mocks/doubles and just want the dopamine hit of good test coverage. This is a highly questionable enterprise in my view and denigrates the sound FIRST  principles of good unit tests. I'm not against that sort of testing - it certainly has its place, but I think they should be clearly identified for what they are.

The above answers are great. To add some vocabulary, there are some layers in between, if you follow e.g. the ISTQB's definitions

components tests test a single unit of code, e.g. a python module, or a java class; this is what you called "unit tests" above
component integration tests test the interaction between different modules
system tests test the system without relying on other systems
system integration tests integrate several systems together; this is what you called "integration tests" above


Why isn't there encouragement for higher level "unit" testing that tests multiple objects at a time?

Maybe because people are not aware of these different stages?

Why does testing have to only be single object unit test and full application integration tests?

It does not.

Thanks.
I think what I'm describing is in the "system test" category.  But to me, system tests would include performance and load testing, which I'm not trying to do.

@Thor: you can do performance and load testing at several levels. Most often, it's done at the system level, though. I actually though you were mostly concerned with component integration tests .

if an anonymous @downvoter were to explain, this could potentially be improved

Unit tests test parts of your system in isolation, and mock anything external to that part of the system.
That part may be a single class, or a number of classes working together to achieve a specific technical (or even functional) goal. Mocking of things external to that part is done to guarantee that the input received from is always reliably the same, and that it's easy (through the mocking) to analyse that anything sent to that external part is reliably the same too. It also has the advantage that slow external systems (think web services, databases, etc.) don't slow down your tests and won't fail your tests if they're down or give wrong data.
Integration tests otoh specifically test the interactions with such external parts and systems. Different thing, different purpose.
